# Antlr4 compile ASN.1

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, asn.1

Antlr4 gives me an error by compiling the following file:

```
IEEE1609dot2 {iso(1) identified-organization(3) ieee(111) 
standards-association-numbered-series-standards(2) wave-stds(1609)  
dot2(2) base (1) schema (1) major-version-2(2)}


DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS::= BEGIN 

EXPORTS ALL;

IMPORTS 
  CrlSeries,
  EccP256CurvePoint,
  EciesP256EncryptedKey,
  EncryptionKey,
  GeographicRegion,
  GroupLinkageValue,
  HashAlgorithm,
  HashedId3,
  HashedId8,
  Hostname,
  IValue,
  LinkageValue,
  Opaque,
  Psid,
  PsidSsp,
  PsidSspRange,
  PublicEncryptionKey,
  PublicVerificationKey,
  SequenceOfHashedId3,
  SequenceOfPsidSsp,
  SequenceOfPsidSspRange,
  ServiceSpecificPermissions,
  Signature,
  SubjectAssurance,
  SymmetricEncryptionKey,
  ThreeDLocation,
  Time64,
  Uint3,
  Uint8,
  Uint16, 
  Uint32,
  ValidityPeriod
FROM IEEE1609dot2BaseTypes {iso(1) identified-organization(3) ieee(111) 
    standards-association-numbered-series-standards(2) wave-stds(1609)  
    dot2(2) base(1) base-types(2)  major-version-2 (2)}

;
SignedDataPayload ::= SEQUENCE  { 
    data              Ieee1609Dot2Data OPTIONAL,
    extDataHash       HashedData OPTIONAL,
    ...
}
    (WITH COMPONENTS {..., data PRESENT} |
     WITH COMPONENTS {..., extDataHash PRESENT})

Ieee1609Dot2Data ::= SEQUENCE  {
    protocolVersion    Uint8(3),
    content            Ieee1609Dot2Content
}

Ieee1609Dot2Content ::=  CHOICE  { 
    unsecuredData            Opaque, 
    signedData               SignedData,
    encryptedData            EncryptedData,
    signedCertificateRequest Opaque,
    ...
}

SignedData ::= SEQUENCE  { 
    hashId          HashAlgorithm,
    tbsData         ToBeSignedData,
    signer          SignerIdentifier,
    signature       Signature
}

SignerIdentifier ::= CHOICE  { 
    digest          HashedId8,
    certificate     SequenceOfCertificate,
    self            NULL,
    ...
}

ToBeSignedData ::= SEQUENCE  { 
    payload         SignedDataPayload,
    headerInfo      HeaderInfo
}

HashedData::= CHOICE  { 
    sha256HashedData  OCTET STRING (SIZE(32)),
    ...
}

HeaderInfo ::= SEQUENCE  { 
    psid                   Psid,
    generationTime         Time64 OPTIONAL,
    expiryTime             Time64  OPTIONAL,
    generationLocation     ThreeDLocation OPTIONAL,
    p2pcdLearningRequest   HashedId3 OPTIONAL,
    missingCrlIdentifier   MissingCrlIdentifier OPTIONAL,
    encryptionKey          EncryptionKey OPTIONAL,
    ...,
    inlineP2pcdRequest     SequenceOfHashedId3 OPTIONAL,
    requestedCertificate   Certificate OPTIONAL
}

MissingCrlIdentifier ::= SEQUENCE  {
    cracaId         HashedId3,
    crlSeries       CrlSeries,
    ...
}

Countersignature ::= Ieee1609Dot2Data (WITH COMPONENTS {...,
  content (WITH COMPONENTS {..., 
    signedData  (WITH COMPONENTS {..., 
      tbsData (WITH COMPONENTS {..., 
        payload (WITH COMPONENTS {..., 
          data ABSENT,
          extDataHash PRESENT
        }),
        headerInfo(WITH COMPONENTS {..., 
          generationTime PRESENT,
          expiryTime ABSENT,
          generationLocation ABSENT,
          p2pcdLearningRequest ABSENT,
          missingCrlIdentifier ABSENT,
          encryptionKey ABSENT
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
EncryptedData ::= SEQUENCE  {
    recipients     SequenceOfRecipientInfo,
    ciphertext     SymmetricCiphertext
}
RecipientInfo ::= CHOICE  {
    pskRecipInfo        PreSharedKeyRecipientInfo,
    symmRecipInfo       SymmRecipientInfo,
    certRecipInfo       PKRecipientInfo, 
    signedDataRecipInfo PKRecipientInfo, 
    rekRecipInfo        PKRecipientInfo 
}

SequenceOfRecipientInfo ::= SEQUENCE OF RecipientInfo

PreSharedKeyRecipientInfo ::= HashedId8
SymmRecipientInfo ::= SEQUENCE  { 
    recipientId        HashedId8, 
    encKey             SymmetricCiphertext
}

PKRecipientInfo ::= SEQUENCE  { 
    recipientId        HashedId8, 
    encKey             EncryptedDataEncryptionKey
}

EncryptedDataEncryptionKey ::= CHOICE  { 
    eciesNistP256          EciesP256EncryptedKey,
    eciesBrainpoolP256r1   EciesP256EncryptedKey,
    ...
}

SymmetricCiphertext ::= CHOICE  {
    aes128ccm           AesCcmCiphertext,
    ...
}

AesCcmCiphertext ::= SEQUENCE  {
    nonce           OCTET STRING (SIZE (12)),
    ccmCiphertext   Opaque -- 16 bytes longer than plaintext
}
Certificate ::= CertificateBase (ImplicitCertificate | ExplicitCertificate)

SequenceOfCertificate ::= SEQUENCE OF Certificate

CertificateBase ::= SEQUENCE  {
    version                 Uint8(3),
    type                    CertificateType,
    issuer                  IssuerIdentifier,
    toBeSigned              ToBeSignedCertificate,
    signature               Signature OPTIONAL
}

CertificateType  ::= ENUMERATED  {
    explicit,
    implicit,
    ...
}

ImplicitCertificate ::= CertificateBase (WITH COMPONENTS {...,
    type(implicit),
    toBeSigned(WITH COMPONENTS {..., 
      verifyKeyIndicator(WITH COMPONENTS {reconstructionValue})
    }), 
    signature ABSENT
    })

ExplicitCertificate ::= CertificateBase (WITH COMPONENTS {...,
    type(explicit),
    toBeSigned(WITH COMPONENTS {..., 
        verifyKeyIndicator(WITH COMPONENTS {verificationKey})
    }), 
    signature PRESENT
    })

IssuerIdentifier ::= CHOICE  { 
    sha256AndDigest         HashedId8,
    self                    HashAlgorithm,
    ...,
    sha384AndDigest         HashedId8
}

ToBeSignedCertificate ::= SEQUENCE  { 
    id                     CertificateId,
    cracaId                HashedId3,
    crlSeries              CrlSeries,
    validityPeriod         ValidityPeriod,
    region                 GeographicRegion OPTIONAL,
    assuranceLevel         SubjectAssurance OPTIONAL,
    appPermissions         SequenceOfPsidSsp OPTIONAL,
    certIssuePermissions   SequenceOfPsidGroupPermissions OPTIONAL,
    certRequestPermissions SequenceOfPsidGroupPermissions OPTIONAL, 
    canRequestRollover     NULL OPTIONAL,
    encryptionKey          PublicEncryptionKey OPTIONAL,
    verifyKeyIndicator     VerificationKeyIndicator,
    ...
}
(WITH COMPONENTS { ..., appPermissions PRESENT} |
 WITH COMPONENTS { ..., certIssuePermissions PRESENT} |
 WITH COMPONENTS { ..., certRequestPermissions PRESENT})

CertificateId ::= CHOICE  {
    linkageData             LinkageData,
    name                    Hostname,
    binaryId                OCTET STRING(SIZE(1..64)),
    none                    NULL,
    ...
}

LinkageData ::= SEQUENCE  {
    iCert                 IValue,
    linkage-value         LinkageValue, 
    group-linkage-value   GroupLinkageValue OPTIONAL
}

--EndEntityType ::= BIT STRING {app (0), enrol (1) } (SIZE (8)) (ALL EXCEPT {})
EndEntityType ::= BIT STRING {app (0), enrol (1) } (SIZE (8))

PsidGroupPermissions ::= SEQUENCE  {
    subjectPermissions SubjectPermissions,
    minChainLength     INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
    chainLengthRange   INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
    eeType             EndEntityType DEFAULT '00'H
}

SequenceOfPsidGroupPermissions ::= SEQUENCE OF PsidGroupPermissions

SubjectPermissions ::= CHOICE  {
    explicit        SequenceOfPsidSspRange,
    all             NULL,
    ...
}

VerificationKeyIndicator ::= CHOICE  {
    verificationKey         PublicVerificationKey,
    reconstructionValue     EccP256CurvePoint,
    ...
}

END
```

and the grammar, I used:

```
moduleDefinition:  
    moduleIdentifier
    DEFINITIONS_LITERAL
    // encodingReferenceDefault?
    tagDefault?
    extensionDefault?
    ASSIGN
    BEGIN_LITERAL
    ( exports? imports? assignment assignment* )?   // moduleBody
    // encodingControlSections?
    END_LITERAL
;

moduleIdentifier: 
    UCASE_ID  // modulereference
    ( definitiveOID  /* iRIValue? */ )?    // DefinitiveIdentification
;

definitiveOID:
    LCURLY
    definitiveObjIdComponent definitiveObjIdComponent*
    RCURLY
;

definitiveObjIdComponent:
    LCASE_ID     
    | NUMBER     
    | ( LCASE_ID LPAREN NUMBER RPAREN )
;

tagDefault:
    ( EXPLICIT_LITERAL | IMPLICIT_LITERAL | AUTOMATIC_LITERAL ) TAGS_LITERAL
;

extensionDefault:
    EXTENSIBILITY_LITERAL IMPLIED_LITERAL
;

exports:
    EXPORTS_LITERAL ( symbolList? | ALL_LITERAL ) SEMI 
;

imports:
    IMPORTS_LITERAL symbolsFromModuleList? SEMI
;

symbolsFromModuleList:
    symbolsFromModule symbolsFromModule*
;

symbolsFromModule:
    symbolList FROM_LITERAL globalModuleReference
;

globalModuleReference:
    UCASE_ID assignedIdentifier?
;

assignedIdentifier:
    definitiveOID  
    | LCASE_ID // definedValue
;

symbolList:
    symbol ( COMMA symbol )*
;

symbol:
    // reference | parameterizedReference (we simplify)
    UCASE_ID | LCASE_ID
;

assignment:
    typeAssignment
    | valueAssignment
//  | xMLValueAssignment
//  | valueSetTypeAssignment
//  | objectClassAssignment
//  | objectAssignment
//  | objectSetAssignment
//  | parameterizedAssignment
;


/* TypeAssignment (see 16.1 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
typeAssignment:
    UCASE_ID // typereference
    ASSIGN
    type
;

/* BuiltinType (see 17.1 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
type:
    builtinType constraint?
    | referencedType constraint?
    //| constrainedType 
;

builtinType:
    bitStringType
    | BOOLEAN_LITERAL // BooleanType
    | characterStringType
    | choiceType
    | DATE_LITERAL  // DateType
    | DATE_TIME_LITERAL // DateTimeType
    | DURATION_LITERAL  // DurationType
    | EMBEDDED_LITERAL PDV_LITERAL // EmbeddedPDVType
    | enumeratedType
    | EXTERNAL_LITERAL // ExternalType
//  | InstanceOfType (Rec. ITU-T X.681 | ISO/IEC 8824-2, Annex C)
    | integerType
    | OID_IRI_LITERAL // IRIType
    | NULL_LITERAL // NullType
//  | ObjectClassFieldType (Rec. ITU-T X.681 | ISO/IEC 8824-2, 14.1)
    | OBJECT_LITERAL IDENTIFIER_LITERAL // ObjectIdentifierType
    | OCTET_LITERAL STRING_LITERAL // OctetStringType
    | REAL_LITERAL  // RealType
    | RELATIVE_OID_IRI_LITERAL // RelativeIRIType
    | RELATIVE_OID_LITERAL // RelativeOIDType
    | sequenceType
    | sequenceOfType
    | setType
    | setOfType
    | prefixedType 
    | TIME_LITERAL // TimeType
    | TIME_OF_DAY_LITERAL // TimeOfDayType
;

/* ReferencedType (see 17.3 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
referencedType:
    usefulType
    | definedType
    | selectionType
//  | TypeFromObject
//  | ValueSetFromObjects
;

definedType:
    UCASE_ID  // typereference
    | ( UCASE_ID DOT UCASE_ID )  // modulereference.typereference
;

usefulType:
   GeneralizedTime_LITERAL
   | UTCTime_LITERAL
   | ObjectDescriptor_LITERAL
;

/* SelectionType (see 30 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
selectionType:
    LCASE_ID LESS_THAN type
;

/* BitStringType (see 22.1 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
bitStringType:
    BIT_LITERAL STRING_LITERAL
    ( LCURLY namedBitList RCURLY )?
;

namedBitList:
    namedBit ( COMMA namedBit )*
;

namedBit:
    LCASE_ID LPAREN NUMBER RPAREN
    | LCASE_ID LPAREN LCASE_ID RPAREN
;

/* EnumeratedType (see 20.1 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
enumeratedType:
    ENUMERATED_LITERAL
    LCURLY 
    enumeration
    ( COMMA ELLIPSIS /* exceptionSpec? */ ( COMMA enumeration )? )? 
    RCURLY 
;

enumeration:
    enumerationItem ( COMMA enumerationItem )*
;

enumerationItem:
    LCASE_ID | namedNumber
;
integerType:
    INTEGER_LITERAL 
    ( LCURLY namedNumberList RCURLY )?
;

namedNumberList:
    namedNumber ( COMMA namedNumber )*
;

namedNumber:
    LCASE_ID LPAREN signedNumber RPAREN
    | LCASE_ID LPAREN LCASE_ID RPAREN   // definedValue
;

signedNumber:
    MINUS? NUMBER
;

characterStringType:
    // RestrictedCharacterString types
    BMPString_LITERAL
    | GeneralString_LITERAL
    | GraphicString_LITERAL
    | IA5String_LITERAL
    | ISO646String_LITERAL
    | NumericString_LITERAL
    | PrintableString_LITERAL
    | TeletexString_LITERAL
    | T61String_LITERAL
    | UniversalString_LITERAL
    | UTF8String_LITERAL
    | VideotexString_LITERAL
    | VisibleString_LITERAL
    // UnrestrictedCharacterString type
    | CHARACTER_LITERAL STRING_LITERAL
;

choiceType:
    CHOICE_LITERAL 
    LCURLY  
    alternativeTypeList ( COMMA extensionAndException extensionAdditionAlternatives? extensionMarker? )?
    RCURLY
;

extensionAdditionAlternatives:
    COMMA extensionAdditionAlternativesList
;

extensionAdditionAlternativesList:
    extensionAdditionAlternative ( COMMA extensionAdditionAlternative )*
;

extensionAdditionAlternative:
    extensionAdditionAlternativesGroup
    | namedType
;

extensionAdditionAlternativesGroup:
    DOUBLE_LBRACKET ( NUMBER COLON )? alternativeTypeList DOUBLE_RBRACKET
;

alternativeTypeList:
   namedType ( COMMA namedType )*
;

namedType:
    LCASE_ID type
;

/* SequenceType (see 25 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
sequenceType:
    SEQUENCE_LITERAL LCURLY componentTypeLists? RCURLY
;

/* SetType (see 27 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
setType:
    SET_LITERAL LCURLY componentTypeLists? RCURLY
;

componentTypeLists:
    componentTypeList  # rootComponentOnly
    | componentTypeList COMMA extensionAndException extensionAdditions? extensionMarker? # rootComponentsAndExtensions
    | componentTypeList COMMA extensionAndException extensionAdditions? extensionMarker COMMA componentTypeList # rootComponentsAndExtensionsAndAdditions
    | extensionAndException extensionAdditions? extensionMarker COMMA componentTypeList # extensionsAndAdditions
    | extensionAndException extensionAdditions? extensionMarker? # extensionsOnly
;

extensionAndException:
    ELLIPSIS exceptionSpec? 
;

exceptionSpec:
    EXCLAMATION exceptionIdentification
;

exceptionIdentification:
    signedNumber
    | LCASE_ID  // definedValue
    | type COLON value
;

extensionMarker:
    COMMA ELLIPSIS
;

extensionAdditions:
    COMMA extensionAdditionList
;

extensionAdditionList:
    extensionAddition ( COMMA extensionAddition )*
;

extensionAddition:
    componentType
    | extensionAdditionGroup
;

extensionAdditionGroup:
    DOUBLE_LBRACKET ( NUMBER COLON )? componentTypeList DOUBLE_RBRACKET
;

componentTypeList:
    componentType ( COMMA componentType )*
;

componentType:
    namedType
    | namedType OPTIONAL_LITERAL
    | namedType DEFAULT_LITERAL value
    | COMPONENTS_LITERAL OF_LITERAL type
;

/* SequenceOfType (see 26 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
sequenceOfType:
    SEQUENCE_LITERAL ( SIZE_LITERAL? constraint )? OF_LITERAL ( namedType | type )
;

/* SetOfType (see 28 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
setOfType:
    SET_LITERAL ( SIZE_LITERAL? constraint )? OF_LITERAL ( namedType | type )
;

/* PrefixedType  (see 31 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
prefixedType:
    taggedType
//  | encodingPrefixedType
;

taggedType:
    LBRACKET 
    ( UCASE_ID COLON )?   /* encodingreference (see 12.25 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) should be all uppercase but it creates ambiguities */
    ( UNIVERSAL_LITERAL | APPLICATION_LITERAL | PRIVATE_LITERAL )?   // Class
    ( NUMBER | LCASE_ID ) // ClassNumber
    RBRACKET 
    ( IMPLICIT_LITERAL | EXPLICIT_LITERAL )?
    type
;

/*--------------------- Values ------------------------------------------------------*/

valueAssignment:
    LCASE_ID
    type
    ASSIGN
    value
;

value:
    CSTRING                                                    # value_CSTRING
    | BSTRING                                                  # value_BSTRING  
    | HSTRING                                                  # value_HSTRING    
    | LCURLY RCURLY                                            # value_EmptyList    
    | (TRUE_LITERAL | FALSE_LITERAL)                           # value_BOOLEAN
    | LCASE_ID COLON value                                     # value_Choice    
    | LCURLY namedValue ( COMMA namedValue )* RCURLY           # value_NamedValueList
    | LCURLY objIdComponents  objIdComponents* RCURLY          # value_ObjectIdentifier
    | LCURLY value ( COMMA value )* RCURLY                     # value_ValueList
    | MINUS? ( NUMBER | NUMBER_WITH_DECIMALS )                 # value_Integer 
    | NULL_LITERAL                                             # value_NULL
    | valueReference                                           # value_ReferencedValue
;

namedValue:
    LCASE_ID value
;

valueReference:
    LCASE_ID                          // valuereference                      
    | ( UCASE_ID DOT LCASE_ID )       // modulereference.valuereference                       
;

objIdComponents:
    LCASE_ID
    | NUMBER
    | LCASE_ID LPAREN NUMBER RPAREN
;


/*--------------------- Constraints -------------------------------------------------*/

/* Constraint (see 49.6 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
constraint:
    LPAREN 
    subtypeConstraint
//  ( EXCLAMATION exceptionIdentification )?
    RPAREN
;

subtypeConstraint:
    elementSetSpec ( COMMA ELLIPSIS elementSetSpec? )?
;

elementSetSpec:
    unions
    | ALL_LITERAL EXCEPT_LITERAL elements   // exclusions
;

unions:
    intersections ( ( PIPE | UNION_LITERAL ) intersections )*
;

intersections:
    intersectionElements ( ( POWER | INTERSECTION_LITERAL ) intersectionElements)*
;

intersectionElements:
    elements ( EXCEPT_LITERAL elements)?
;

elements:
    subtypeElements
    | LPAREN elementSetSpec RPAREN
;

/* Subtype elements (see 51 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
subtypeElements:
    value
    | INCLUDES_LITERAL? type
    | valueRange  // including DurationRange, TimePointRange, RecurrenceRange
    | SIZE_LITERAL constraint
    | type
    | FROM_LITERAL constraint
    | WITH_LITERAL COMPONENT_LITERAL constraint
    | WITH_LITERAL COMPONENTS_LITERAL LCURLY ( ELLIPSIS COMMA )? typeConstraints RCURLY
    | PATTERN_LITERAL CSTRING
 // | SETTINGS_LITERAL propertyAndSettingPair propertyAndSettingPair*
;

valueRange:
    ( value | MIN_LITERAL ) LESS_THAN? RANGE LESS_THAN? ( value | MAX_LITERAL )
;

typeConstraints:
    namedConstraint (COMMA namedConstraint)*
;

namedConstraint:
    LCASE_ID constraint? ( PRESENT_LITERAL | ABSENT_LITERAL | OPTIONAL_LITERAL )?
;
DEFINITIONS_LITERAL:
    'DEFINITIONS'
;

BEGIN_LITERAL:
    'BEGIN'
;

END_LITERAL:
    'END'
;

INTEGER_LITERAL:
    'INTEGER'
;

EXPLICIT_LITERAL:
    'EXPLICIT'
;

IMPLICIT_LITERAL:
    'IMPLICIT'
;

AUTOMATIC_LITERAL:
    'AUTOMATIC'
;

TAGS_LITERAL:
    'TAGS'
;

EXTENSIBILITY_LITERAL:
    'EXTENSIBILITY'
;

IMPLIED_LITERAL:
    'IMPLIED'
;

EXPORTS_LITERAL:
    'EXPORTS'
;

IMPORTS_LITERAL:
    'IMPORTS'
;

FROM_LITERAL:
    'FROM'
;

ALL_LITERAL:
    'ALL'
;

BOOLEAN_LITERAL:
    'BOOLEAN'
;

NULL_LITERAL:
    'NULL'
;

BMPString_LITERAL:
    'BMPString'
;

GeneralString_LITERAL:
    'GeneralString'
;

GraphicString_LITERAL:
    'GraphicString'
;

IA5String_LITERAL:
    'IA5String'
;

ISO646String_LITERAL:
    'ISO646String'
;

NumericString_LITERAL:
    'NumericString'
;

PrintableString_LITERAL:
    'PrintableString'
;

TeletexString_LITERAL:
    'TeletexString'
;

T61String_LITERAL:
    'T61String'
;

UniversalString_LITERAL:
    'UniversalString'
;

UTF8String_LITERAL:
    'UTF8String'
;

VideotexString_LITERAL:
    'VideotexString'
;

VisibleString_LITERAL:
    'VisibleString'
;

CHARACTER_LITERAL:
    'CHARACTER'
;

OCTET_LITERAL:
    'OCTET'
;

STRING_LITERAL:
    'STRING'
;

REAL_LITERAL:
    'REAL'
;

BIT_LITERAL:
    'BIT'
;

DATE_LITERAL:
    'DATE'
;

DATE_TIME_LITERAL:
    'DATE-TIME'
;

DURATION_LITERAL:
    'DURATION'
;

TIME_LITERAL:
    'TIME'
;

TIME_OF_DAY_LITERAL:
    'TIME-OF-DAY'
;

ENUMERATED_LITERAL:
    'ENUMERATED'
;

EMBEDDED_LITERAL:
    'EMBEDDED'
;

PDV_LITERAL:
    'PDV'
;

EXTERNAL_LITERAL:
    'EXTERNAL'
;

OID_IRI_LITERAL:
    'OID-IRI'
;

OBJECT_LITERAL:
    'OBJECT'
;

IDENTIFIER_LITERAL:
    'IDENTIFIER'
;

RELATIVE_OID_IRI_LITERAL:
    'RELATIVE-OID-IRI'
;

RELATIVE_OID_LITERAL:
    'RELATIVE-OID'
;

CHOICE_LITERAL:
    'CHOICE'
;

SEQUENCE_LITERAL:
    'SEQUENCE'
;

SET_LITERAL:
    'SET'
;

OF_LITERAL:
    'OF'
;

UNIVERSAL_LITERAL:
    'UNIVERSAL'
;

APPLICATION_LITERAL:
    'APPLICATION'
;

PRIVATE_LITERAL:
    'PRIVATE'
;

OPTIONAL_LITERAL:
    'OPTIONAL'
;

COMPONENTS_LITERAL:
    'COMPONENTS'
;

PATTERN_LITERAL:
    'PATTERN'
;

TRUE_LITERAL:
    'TRUE'
;

FALSE_LITERAL:
    'FALSE'
;

SIZE_LITERAL:
    'SIZE'
;

EXCEPT_LITERAL:
    'EXCEPT'
;

UNION_LITERAL:
    'UNION'
;

INTERSECTION_LITERAL:
    'INTERSECTION'
;

MIN_LITERAL:
    'MIN'
;

MAX_LITERAL:
    'MAX'
;

INCLUDES_LITERAL:
    'INCLUDES'
;

WITH_LITERAL:
    'WITH'
;

COMPONENT_LITERAL:
    'COMPONENT'
;

PRESENT_LITERAL:
    'PRESENT'
;

ABSENT_LITERAL:
    'ABSENT'
;

DEFAULT_LITERAL:
    'DEFAULT'
;

GeneralizedTime_LITERAL:
    'GeneralizedTime'
;

UTCTime_LITERAL:
    'UTCTime'
;

ObjectDescriptor_LITERAL:
    'ObjectDescriptor'
;

/*--------------------- Lexical Items -----------------------------------------------*/

ASSIGN:
    '::='
;

LCURLY:
    '{'
;

RCURLY:
    '}'
;

LBRACKET:
    '['
;

RBRACKET:
    ']'
;

DOUBLE_LBRACKET:
    '[['
;

DOUBLE_RBRACKET:
    ']]'
;

LPAREN:
    '('
;

RPAREN:
    ')'
;

SEMI:
    ';'
;

COMMA:
    ','
;

MINUS:
    '-'
;

DOT:
    '.'
;

LESS_THAN:
    '<'
;

COLON:
    ':'
;

APOSTROPHE:
    '\''
;

ELLIPSIS:
    '...'
;

RANGE:
    '..'
;

POWER:  
    '^'
;

PIPE:
    '|'
;

EXCLAMATION:
    '!'
;





BSTRING: 
    APOSTROPHE ('0'..'1')* '\'B'
;

HSTRING:
    APOSTROPHE ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F')* '\'H'
;

CSTRING:  
    '"' ( EscapeSequence | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"'
;

fragment EscapeSequence:   
    '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'"'|APOSTROPHE|'\\')
;

/* typereference (see 12.2 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
UCASE_ID:
    ('A'..'Z') ('-'('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')|('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'))* 
;

LCASE_ID:
    ('a'..'z') ('-'('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')|('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'))* 
;

/* comment (see 12.6 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
LINE_COMMENT: 
    '--' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' ->skip
; 

/* white-space (see 12.1.6 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
WS:
    (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n') -> skip
;

/* number (see 12.8 in ITU-T X.680 (08/2015) */
NUMBER:
    '0' | ('1'..'9')('0'..'9')*
;

NUMBER_WITH_DECIMALS:
    ('0'..'9')('0'..'9')* '.' ('0'..'9')('0'..'9')*
;

OTHER:
    .
;
```

by compiling I get an error :

ERROR MSG:

```
Symbol 'CrlSeries' is imported in module 'IEEE1609dot2' from an undefined module 'IEEE1609dot2BaseTypes' 
Symbol 'SequenceOfPsidSspRange' is imported in module 'IEEE1609dot2' from an undefined module 'IEEE1609dot2BaseTypes'
Symbol 'ServiceSpecificPermissions' is imported in module 'IEEE1609dot2' from an undefined module 'IEEE1609dot2BaseTypes'
Symbol 'Signature' is imported in module 'IEEE1609dot2' from an undefined module 'IEEE1609dot2BaseTypes'
Symbol 'SubjectAssurance' is imported in module 'IEEE1609dot2' from an undefined module 'IEEE1609dot2BaseTypes' 
Symbol 'ThreeDLocation' is imported in module 'IEEE1609dot2' from an undefined module 'IEEE1609dot2BaseTypes'
Symbol 'Time64' is imported in module 'IEEE1609dot2' from an undefined module 'IEEE1609dot2BaseTypes'
Symbol 'Uint3' is imported in module 'IEEE1609dot2' from an undefined module 'IEEE1609dot2BaseTypes'
Symbol 'Uint8' is imported in module 'IEEE1609dot2' from an undefined module 'IEEE1609dot2BaseTypes' 
[line 76:24] Type 'Uint8' neither defined nor imported
[line 81:30] Type 'Opaque' neither defined nor imported
[line 84:30] Type 'Opaque' neither defined nor imported 
[line 115:28] Type 'Time64' neither defined nor imported   
[line 180:24] Type 'HashedId8' neither defined nor imported
```

How can I change the grammar to be more adapted to ASN.1 definition? Because I think the grammar is outdated in comparison to ASN.1.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not an antlr4 message.

This message is produced by the validation step of a [tool](https://github.com/yafred/asn1-tool/) that uses antlr4 to parse an ASN.1 grammar.

So the input file was successfully parsed and there is nothing to change in the grammar that would fix this problem.

You found the right place for your question: https://github.com/yafred/asn1-tool/issues/4